# Android 2.2.1 default video player can't play H.264 file

Tags: android, android-video-player

I found that the default video player on Android 2.2.1 can't play the format of H.264(640*320) video file, instead it can play the format of H.263(353*288) video file.

However, the quality of H.263 video is very bad, anyone can suggest how to make the Android 2.2.1 default player can play H.264 video?

Other solution is welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a lower resolution H.264 video?

Comment: I think this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364190/what-h-264-format-loads-on-android-and-ios/6364801#6364801

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html), Android supports h.264 Baseline Profile playback. So your h.264 video is not Baseline Profile or possibly it contains an unsupported audio.

You should note that there are many h.64 flavors, so you should check your video file: http://www.niallkennedy.com/blog/2010/07/h264-video.html