# VideoView can't play video error

Tags: android, youtube, android-videoview

I'm trying to play youtube video from URL in my VideoView, but i'm getting "Can't play video error", bellow is my code, what i'm doing wrong?

```
public class YoutubeVideoPopUpActivity extends Activity {

    private String url;

    private VideoView videoView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube_video);

        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        //url = intent.getStringExtra("Url");
        url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=INu_z8Zn2R8";
        setUpVideo();
    }

    private void setUpVideo() {
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the url you are trying to use is just a normal html - page (youtube) not the actual video. this way it can't work. 
have a look at the official youtube api: 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

or try to open the url with a new intent:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hxy8BZGQ5Jo")));
```

this should open the video in a webview or the installed youtube app....

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806261/strange-behavior-of-android-videoview-cant-play-video) this could be due to:

- Unsupported file format
- Unsupported codecs
- Erroneous content

and it is unlikely it is a problem with your application.