# Can't play this video. Android videoView mp4 recorded by android device

Tags: java, android, video, video-codecs

[image]

I've looked for existing potential solutions with other `formats` and those still responds with mentioned error.

Finally, recorded the video with the same device and used it as a resource for this app and it still doesn't work.

Devices: `SGS2`, lenovo `a820`

Video type: `MPEG-4 video (video/mp4)`

```
    videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://raw/sample.mp4");
    videoView.start();
```

Comment: Check [this][1] thread for the explanation.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806261/strange-behavior-of-android-videoview-cant-play-video

Comment: This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882785/cant-play-this-video-error-using-url-with-videoview-and-mediacontroller#:~:text=Add%20a%20comment-,1,Hope%20this%20will%20help.,-Share

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please refer below code snippet...problem was with the path declaration..

```
 String uriPath = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.aha_hands_only_cpr_english;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
```

Thats it...

Comment: try this link: http://androidexample.com/Play_Video_File_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=124&aaid=144 it works for me...

Comment: after this add 
mVideoView.start();

Answer (score 12):

I tried everything mentioned before but it turns out that internet permission is needed to play a mp4 file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try following code..

```
videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file;
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
videoView.setMediaController(mc);
videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class videoplayer extends Activity {
    private static final String Videos_URL = "*your URI*";

    private VideoView myVideoView;
    private int position = 0;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private MediaController mediaControls;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the layout from video_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (mediaControls == null) {
            mediaControls = new MediaController(this);
        }

        // Find your VideoView in your video_main.xml layout
        myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        // Create a progressbar
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Set progressbar title
        progressDialog.setTitle("ABCDEFGH");
        // Set progressbar message
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");

        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // Show progressbar
        progressDialog.show();

        try {
            Uri video = Uri.parse(Videos_URL);
            myVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
            myVideoView.setMediaController(mediaControls);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        myVideoView.requestFocus();
        myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                myVideoView.seekTo(position);
                if (position == 0) {
                    myVideoView.start();
                } else {
                    myVideoView.pause();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("Position", myVideoView.getCurrentPosition());
        myVideoView.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        position = savedInstanceState.getInt("Position");
        myVideoView.seekTo(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx Andrii.. Actually i was getting late for my class.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that the decoder (target sdk) supports the video format you are using. You can use VLC Player to convert video format to the desired one. In my case, I converted the MP4 to WebM file and load it in the VideoView.

Here is how you get the file path and play your video.

```
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sample;
VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
videoView.start()
```

Source:
**Video format and codec support**
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

For Lenovo a820 ,below is need :

```
- MP4/WMV/H.264/H.263 player
- MP3/WAV/WMA/eAAC+ player
```

make sure that ur video fits in above codec format.

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace your code with this code and it will be working:

```
VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sample);
        videoView.start();
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include an explanation of *how* this code block answers the question. This makes your answer much more useful to those who come across the same issue later on.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the device on which we try to play video, sometimes it doesn't support.
I tried running it on Linux emulatoe

Answer (score -1):

**Try this following code it works..........**

```
VideoView videoView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.videoname;

videoView.start();
```