# Viewing mp4-video using VideoView displays a black screen

Tags: java, android-videoview

I need play this video in my android app:
"https://storage.weacom.ru/movies/2018_02/12_WTV_zimnik_640.mp4"
But i see black screen, look my code:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

VideoView vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
String vidAddress = "https://storage.weacom.ru/movies/2018_02/12_WTV_zimnik_640.mp4";
Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);

    MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
    vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
    vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);

vidView.start();


}
```

}

Comment: in manifetst i write:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
private VideoView videoView;

videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

Uri video = Uri.parse("Your_link");
MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
videoView.setAnchorView(vidControl);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
  @Override       
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
       mp.setLooping(true);
       videoView.start();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: 09-30 20:39:01.820 10708-10722/com.example.viktor.videotest E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
09-30 20:39:01.821 10708-10708/com.example.viktor.videotest E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 VideoView vidView;
 ProgressDialog dialog;
MediaController controller;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
          vidView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
          dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "wait", "Buffering         
    video...", false);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
         controller = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);
        String vidAddress = "https://storage.weacom.ru/movies/2018_02/12_WTV_zimnik_640.mp4";
        Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
        vidView.setMediaController(controller);
        vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
        vidView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                vidView.start();
            }
        });
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        dialog.dismiss();

    }

}
}
```

if you get "can not play this video" change video format ...

Comment: you mean not .mp4?
after this code i was seen:  "can not play this video"

Comment: @mrjoyn, If you get this error, it is not from your app
 read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806261/strange-behavior-of-android-videoview-cant-play-video