# Android Video View - Can't play this video - Internal Storage

Tags: android, uri, android-videoview

I'm trying to play Video from internal storage using Uri like:

```
Uri video = Uri.parse(pth);
```

Here is URI:

```
String pth = "/data/"+getPackageName()+"/files/Movies/1/2/3/2020-01-15_23-48-23.mp4";
```

Always getting:

```
Can't play this video.
```

**Update # 1**

also tried with `.3gp` format, result same `Can't play this video`

Comment: Have a look here, please https://stackoverflow.com/a/7806881/5339154

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange Behavior of Android VideoView - "Can't Play Video"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806261/strange-behavior-of-android-videoview-cant-play-video)

Comment: @Collin no not at all...