# Converting H.264 to H.263 for android phone

Tags: android

I am receiving continuous live stream of IP camera content in the format of H.264 AVC and I learnt that Android phones with SDK lesser than 3.0 do not support it. Is there a way where I can convert it while receiving it and display in the form if H.263 from my end? I am testing on Samsung Galaxy with OS 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Pre Android 3.0 devices do support H.264 *playback* (ie, decoding). They just don't support H.264 *encoding*. [(See the documentation.)](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) See also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763335/how-to-know-which-android-devices-support-video-playback).

I don't know of any way to convert a live stream to H.263 as the OP asked, but for those who can do the conversion first, FFmpeg is a possible solution.

```
ffmpeg -i /path/to/your/file.h264 -vcodec copy -acodec copy /path/to/your/newfile.h263
```

[*(source)*](https://www.file-extensions.org/convert-h264-to-h263)

But see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6364801/3681880) for a much more specific ffmpeg parameters meant to work on Android.