# Live stream format in iOS

Tags: android, ios, h.264, live-streaming

We have developed video streaming applications for Android and iOS. In this application user can publish video and can view live streams as well. App is working fine from iOS to iOS but can not play on Android. If we publish from Android then it plays on Android, RTMP flash player but not on iOS.

From iOS we are publishing video in H.264 format and Android supports H.264 then why it's not playing on Android?

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, but It could be a problem with file extension. iOS may expect *.m4v and I'm not sure if the Android can manage it. Also check this topic, it may help you: [What h.264 format loads on android AND IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364190/what-h-264-format-loads-on-android-and-ios)