# Error Uploading Video to Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am receiving an error when I attempt to upload my video to Parse.  The error is client side and is that the variable path is found nil.  Perhaps I am declaring this wrong or using pathForResource wrong but I appreciate any help that I would be able to get.

```
 func Upload() {
    var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("big_buck_bunny_720p_2mb.mp4", ofType: "mp4")
    var videodata: NSData?
    videodata = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(path!) as? NSData


    let file = PFFile(name:"capturedVideo", data:videodata!)
    file!.saveInBackground()

}
```

Comment: try printing out each variable after you declare them to see which one is nil. It's probably a problem with the path variable that's affecting you PFFile.

Comment: I'm aware its a problem with the path variable, I already stated the in the question, I am curious as to whether or no that is the right format

Comment: this should give you an idea of something to try since the path is returning nil: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401417/unable-to-play-mp4-video-file-from-mainbundle