# how to get video to nextView when i click button in iOS?

Tags: ios

Hi i am getting video in the sameViewController when i clicked video button in same View..But my requirement is want to get video in to secondViewController when we click video button in firstView ..i written code like this

//mainViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)videoClicked:(id)sender
{

imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
imagePicker.mediaTypes =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info
{

NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]){
videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
NSLog(@"videourl %@",videoURL);
}

ViewController *viewC=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

[picker presentViewController:viewC animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

please anybody help me how to do this .help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create property for videoUrl in your secondViewController and set it before presenting.

Comment: can i ask one more thing s.londar

Comment: thank you for replying me..i am using SAVedioRangeSlider(third party api) here..i am getting images into SAvediorangeSlider but not getting video into the secondView

Comment: i want to get video which contains images while playing music

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand question. Could you give more detailed explanation?

Comment: Ok ..i am getting video into secondviewController SaVideoRangeSlider from when i click video Button ..so Apart from this i want to get video into into secondView

Comment: You want to play it video on some view?

Comment: sorry for late reply s.londar ..yes i want to play on view

Comment: I think you need to use MPMoviePlayerController. Read answers for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266750/iphone-sdkhow-do-you-play-video-inside-a-view-rather-than-fullscreen) question.

Comment: thankq soo much for replying me..yes londar i too also seeing same link